# PhotoManager.getAssetPathList() does not work on real Android device

Tags: android, flutter

I am making an application that loads photos from device using Photomanager, flutter.

The sdk version is 33, and My real device version is galaxy Fold2.

Some partial lines of My code is:

```
class _UploadPageState extends State<UploadPage> {
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loadPhotos();
  }
  var albums = <AssetPathEntity>[];
  var imgList = <AssetEntity>[];
  var headerTitle = '';
  AssetEntity? selected;
  void _loadPhotos() async {
    var result = await PhotoManager.requestPermissionExtend();
    if(result.isAuth){
      albums = await PhotoManager.getAssetPathList(
          type:RequestType.all,
      filterOption: FilterOptionGroup(
        orders: [OrderOption(type: OrderOptionType.createDate,asc:false)]
      )
    );
      _loadData();
    }
  }
  void _loadData() async{
    print(albums);
    headerTitle = albums.first.name;
    await _pagingPhoto();
    setState(() {
    });
  }
```

This code works well on virtual device, but not at all at real device.
I somehow read that I should add

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

on AndroidManifest.xml so I added. But

```
E/flutter (20039): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Bad state: No element
```

appears.

Please tell me what I missed. It seems that my flutter code fails to get the external storage directory.

Comment: what is your `targetSdk`?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I wrote on build.gradle compileSdkVersion 33, but since I am a student it is not strictly decided.

Comment: Ok. See my answer. And I'd strongly recommend to stick to most recent SDK, so I'd suggest "SDK33 is decided" instead :)

Answer (score 1):

You did not show where you added the `requestLegacyExternalStorage` so just in case, it should be in `<application>` but you also need regular permissions too:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application
    ...
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">
    ...
</application>
```

BUT... if you target SDK 33 (and you do), then this particular entry does nothing in your case, which is ([documented here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage)):

> Apps that run on Android 11 but target Android 10 (API level 29) can still request the `requestLegacyExternalStorage` attribute. ...**After you update your app to target Android 11, the system ignores the requestLegacyExternalStorage flag**.

so you can remove it completely.

What I'd do here, is add a check for empty albums to your `_loadData()` instead to avoid accessing stuff if it's not there:

```dart
void _loadData() async {
  print(albums);
  if (albums.isNotEmpty) {
    headerTitle = albums.first.name;
    await _pagingPhoto();
    setState(() {});
  } else {
    setState(() {
      headerTitle = "No albums found";
    });
    // Do something here. Show a message, a placeholder,
    // option to refresh/retry or whatever.
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer. It seems that It helped eliminating the error, but still albums is empty and the app fails to load any photos. Can you please recommend what to do on //do something here ??

Comment: well, you must almost always account for the fact there's no data you expect, like user might have no photos for you to display etc. I updated the `else` branch of `_loadData()` in my answer